# How can I compare an integer and a file name?

Tags: java, file, int, equals

I am trying to make a login/password program which asks if you have an account and you can also make one.
By account I mean the program will give you a random 8 digit number.
I also have a FileWriter which creates a file based on the ID you were given.  And I have a FileReader which will eventually read what you previously exported to your file so you can update it.

The problem I have is that when I ask the user if they have an account already, if they say yes it will ask the user for their UserID.

My plan was that when it read your UserID it would scan the folder I have my .java file saved in and look for a .txt file with the same name as your UserID.  For example, if you make an account and the UserID it gives you is 12345678 it will create a file named 12345678 and then when you input you UserID it will scan to see if that file exists.

Currently The problem that occurs is the it prints

> Error File Not Found(the catch String I wrote)

even though I have that file in the folder.
I think there is something wrong with how I am comparing to see if the UserID matches any file name.

The "Login" class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Login
{
static Console c;

static Login player1;

public static void main (String[] args)

{
    player1 = new Login ();
    player1.FileReaderTest (25756326);
    //player1.Userlogin (); //I think it has something to do with this
} // main method


public void Userlogin (File input)
{
    c = new Console ();

    Random rand = new Random ();

    c.println ("Hello do you have an account?");
    String Q1 = c.readLine ();
    Q1 = Q1.toUpperCase ();
    if (Q1.equals ("YES"))
    {
        c.println ("Please input your User ID");
        int login = c.readInt ();
        if (String.valueOf(login).equals (input))//I think it has something to do with this
        {
            try
            {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader (input);
                BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader (reader);

                String line1 = buf.readLine ();
                String line2 = buf.readLine ();

                buf.close ();
                c.println (line1);
                c.println (line2);

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                c.println ("Error File Not Found");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                c.println ("ERROR");

            }


        }
    }

    else if (Q1.equals ("NO"))
    {
        c.println ("Please enter your name ");
        String name = c.readLine ();
        int UserID = rand.nextInt (99999999);
        c.println ("Your User ID is " + UserID);
        player1.FileCreation (UserID);
        player1.FileReaderTest (UserID);
    }

    while (!Q1.equals ("YES") && !Q1.equals ("NO")) //While Q1 != YES || NO
    {
        c.println ("Please Answer the question with Yes or No");
        c.println ("Hello do you have an account?");
        String Q2 = c.readLine ();
        Q2 = Q2.toUpperCase ();
        if (Q2.equals ("YES"))
        {
            c.println ("Ok lets start");
            break;
        }
        else if (Q2.equals ("NO"))
        {
            c.println ("Please enter your name ");
            String name = c.readLine ();
            int UserID = rand.nextInt (89999999) + 10000000;
            c.println ("Your User ID is " + UserID);
            player1.FileCreation (UserID);
            player1.FileReaderTest (UserID);
            break;
        }

    } //While Q1 != YES || NO



} //Public void Main


public void FileReaderTest (int UserID)
{
    File input = new File (String.valueOf (UserID));
    player1.Userlogin (input);

    try
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader (input);
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader (reader);

        String line1 = buf.readLine ();
        String line2 = buf.readLine ();


        buf.close ();
        c.println (line1);
        c.println (line2);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        c.println ("Error File Not Found");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        c.println ("ERROR");

    }




}


public void FileCreation (int UserID)
{
    try
    {
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (new FileOutputStream (String.valueOf (UserID)), "utf-8"));
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
    }
}
} // Login class
```

Comment: how can you compare a String with a File ?

Comment: I don't know what this `hsa.Console` class is doing.

Comment: you need to compare it with the file name instead of file

Comment: Have you tried making a configuration file instead? configuration files are easier to read and compare.

Comment: @cricket_007 because our school does not want to get into actual Java we use the hsa console which basically makes a simple jframe for us.

Comment: @Jobin so like input.getName()

Comment: yes........... @Bardia Foroughi

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a `File input`, and you want to compare the *name* of the file, so you instead want

```
String.valueOf(login).equals (input.getName());
```

If you are getting an error on

```
File input = new File (String.valueOf (UserID));
```

then note: `"2.txt"`, for example, is very different than a file named just `"2"` (which is worth mentioning because Windows hides file extensions by default)

And if you aren't giving the full path to the file, then that file has to be in your "classpath", which if you don't understand, better to give the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFound is not thrown after a comparison but by your FileReader when it is created. FileReader tells you that there is not file named as such. Since you said that you did create the file, there can be a few explanations:

- Maybe the file you created is in the wrong folder. The default folder for a java program is the project folder. Make sure that you have your file in the right folder. Else you can give the full path as an argument for the FileReader: "/my/full/path/filename.extension".
- It can also be a problem of extension. If you are using a Windows OS, the extension may be hidden in the file explorer. Right clic on your file and check whether there is such an extension (ex: ".txt")

Eventually you can open the file with a FileWriter under Java, and try to create the file within your program. You will see more easily which file Java is trying to access and it will help you identify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that you need to create the text file associated with the UserId, I would suggest adding the `".txt"` in the `FileReaderTest class`. Something similar to this :

```
File input = new File (String.valueOf (UserID)+".txt");
```

Or more conveniently

```
File input = new File (Integer.toString(UserID)+".txt");
```

I think this solves your query.